# Xtify API to delete TAG from all XIDs - Bulk Untag and Bulk Tag options

Tags: push-notification, xtify

Is there any Xtify API which can delete an existing TAG completely from Xtify (either by API or by Xtify console website)

Concern:
Following API's operate on XID as an input parameter, which means TAG and UNTAG can be done by sending request to Xtify one by one for each XID.

```
https://api.xtify.com/2.0/tags/XID/addtag
https://api.xtify.com/2.0/tags/XID/untag
```

I'm in need of the options

1. where some existing TAG can be removed from Xtify in a single call to Xtify. (Bulk UNTAG)
2. Similarly, I can upload a list of XID and provide TAG name in a single call (bulk tagging)

In case these are not possible, then please suggest best practice in such scenario. I think making call multiple times for each XID may not be an optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for bulk tag / untag in Xtify. Your only option is to change the tags using one call for each XID.

Using settag is a little more efficient than addtag/untag, since it doesn't require as many lookups. However, this works only if you are keeping the list of tags.